# make (cause to be) / correct usage

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use the following sentence

> Heat makes the particles evenly spread

in a sense that the particles are evenly spread because of heat. Or should we use "be" after "the particles", something like this: "Heat makes the particles be evenly spread"? I mean normally with an adjective I would not use "be", like in the sentence "this music makes me happy" but in the sentence above we do not have an adjective so I wonder how it works. Thanks for an explanation!

Comment: Heat makes  the particles  spread evenly - Heat causes the particles to  spread evenly.

Comment: So you mean spread? Because then you would need spread out [over some area]. I spread cheese on my bread. The clouds are spread out evenly across the horizon.

Answer (score 2):

> Heat makes the particles become evenly spread

Is grammatically correct, but an English speaker would find this phrasing strange. A better solution:

> Heat makes the particles spread evenly

also

> Heat makes the particles spread out evenly

"Spread out" implies the particles were located near eachother (clustered) at the beginning and the heat cased them to move away from one another (spread out).

We could avoid "makes" altogether:

> Heat evenly spreads the particles.

and even

> Heat evenly spreads the particles out.

A more extreme deviation:

> Once the gas is in thermal equilibrium, the particles will be evenly spread.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know one can use not only adjectives after *make*, verbs also fit. For example:

> That guy always *makes* her **laugh**.
>
> Don't *make* me **cry** again!